# Participial Phrase

Tags: grammar, participial-phrases

> 1. Pulling down the sleeves of her jersey, she walked inside.
> 2. She walked inside, pulling down the sleeves of her jersey.
> 3. Pulling down the sleeves of her jersey, she walked inside, making a beeline for the counter.
> 4. Pulling down the sleeves, walking inside, she made a beeline for the counter.

I know that both 1 & 2 are Participial Phrase.

Now, I'm having a problem, whether 3 is still a Participial Phrase because for me if we add to the number 1 sentence another phrase, something like "she made a beeline for the counter", then the correct structure must be number 4. I feel like number 3 opposes the rule of parallelism. So here's my question, is number 3 still correct and considered as a Participial Phrase? Or is number 4 incorrect? Please explain.

Comment: Welcome to the site, good question! To me those are all participial constructions. What is this rule of parallelism you speak of? Sentence 3 looks OK. Sentence 4 sounds a bit odd to me, because I think subsequent, adjacent participial constructions are normally conjoined with a conjunction (*and*) rather than a mere comma.

Comment: Yes, it is. Both the 'participial phrases' set off with a comma/commas are grammatically okay, though not especially natural, especially 4. Better to call them clauses, not phrases, by the way.

Comment: @BillJ: Depends on your definition: traditionally, a clause is a finite verb and its dependencies. So *clause* might be ambiguous if you don't know which definition the author uses.

Comment: @Cerberus Non-finite clauses have been accepted for a long time now. Trad grammar is well out of date on this. The OP talks of 'parallelism', but that's not an issue here, as that term usually concerns coordination, and the OP's examples are not coordinate constructions. Non-finite clauses, like the ones in the OP's sentences, are very common in English.

Comment: #3 & #4 seem a bit clunky to me. The main difference between #1 and #2 is that I'd assume in the first version she probably at least *started* (if not completed) the pulling down of the sleeves before moving at all, but the second unambiguously asserts that she did this *while* walking.

Comment: FF is right about the semantic / logical constraints here. Forget about the grammar involved. (3)'[S]he walked inside, making a beeline for the counter' is not ideal because the entering and the aiming for the counter are sequential. (3a) '[S]he walked inside and made a beeline for the counter' is better. (4) is clumsy; twinning participial phrases certainly needs better _what you label coordination_ (less semantic disparateness) and usually uses an 'and'. _Pulling down her sleeves and straightening her hem, she walked inside._

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth No, don't forget the grammar - that's what the OP asked about. It was about whether they were participial phrases and the rules of parallelism - that's grammar.

Comment: @BillJ If you insist on addressing the grammar, the question should be closed as a duplicate. I'm looking at the question-behind-the-question. Grammatically, all these are acceptable (though I'd prefer an'and' rather than a comma in (4)). The argument over whether the adjuncts should be considered phrases or clauses has been covered before. The new point for discussion with these examples is the mis-sequencing of the clauses (which OP labels wrong coordination).

Comment: @BillJ I only seek to correct contributions I think need correcting. Sorry if that includes yours.

Comment: Apologies to the OP. Have your concerns been addressed, or are you still puzzled?

Comment: @BillJ: I know that *clause* is used in the broad sense in some (sub-?)fields, but the narrow sense is used in other fields. I don't know what you mean by "out of date", but in the end it is just a matter of definition, isn't it? I wonder why people sought to change this definition in the first place: what downside is there to the narrow definition? // One could argue that the two participial constructions in sentence no. 4 are...at the same level (trying to avoid contested terms)?

Comment: @Cerberus Well, they have the structure of clauses in that they have subjects (though they're located in the main clauses) and predicates. But it's perhaps too long a topic to fit into the confines of a comment box. But, yes all of the OP's examples would traditionally be called participial phrases. I only made the comment about 'clauses' as a bit of an aside really. I agree; the two 'participial' constructions in no 4. are at the same level in that they are structurally alike, so they don't break any rule of grammar. But as FF, EA and I  pointed out, it is clunky and unnatural.

Comment: @Cerberus  Just one point that might help: participials like the OP's "pulling down the sleeves" can be expanded into an adverbial finite clause "Whilst she was pulling down the sleeves".

Comment: Is 'participial phrase' preferred over 'participle phrase'?  Their constructions are quite rigid (unlike 'adverbial' phrases).  Should I be using 'nounial phrases'?

Answer (score 1):

I think this discussion is worth a full answer.  There's a lot going on here and I'd like to know more.  Trying to follow the thread of comments only brought up more questions for me.

In last two of the OP's examples, there are three things happening, with both sequentiality and simultaneousness, and there's a bit of danglingishness/semi parallelism going on too.

If the issue is grammatical, wouldn't it have to do with the positioning of the -ing's, and the use of commas, without an **and** ?  I see three parts, and my brain wants to break them down like this:

1) Pulling down the sleeves of her jersey = participial

2) Making a beeline for the counter = participial

3) Walked inside = predicate

If I'm getting this at all, the OP's #3 is just a two-part participial that is sliced down the middle and separated by a predicate:

**Pulling down the sleeves of her jersey,** she walked inside, **making a beeline for the counter.**

I looked at another participial question and didn't find an answer there, so I'm glad this one didn't get trashed in the duplicate bin.

This page at Purdue's OWL was really helpful:
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/02/

p.s.  I like #3.  Reading it makes me wonder what's going on at the counter that would make her pull up her sleeves...